# use std::stof in codeblocks

Tags: c++, gcc, codeblocks

I want to convert string to float with stof but it is not working 
Also I was enabled c++ 11 in codeblocks 
but give error me that "stof was not declared in  this scope"
if I use of std::stof yet give error me that it is not member of std
**Here is my code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string x;
    x="23";
    float y=stof(x)+2.1;
    cout<<y;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's your toolchain?

Comment: Code::Block uses outdated buggy MinGW by default. You need to update your compiler toolchain.

Comment: how can I update it?

Comment: excuse me I don't have enough time that search by my own

Comment: This site has an updated mingw with GCC 5.3. It also includes boost which you may not need. http://nuwen.net/mingw.html

Comment: @Masoud So you want us to outsource your research efforts? That information is easy to find. Just google mingw update.

Comment: I thank you very much

Comment: make sure to install mingw-w64 (which never had this bug), not mingw

Comment: I'm confused please help me

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
include <sstream>
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "23";
float f;
ss >> f;
```

Answer (score -2):

You have declared y to be an integer.

By definition, integers do not have fractional or decimal parts.

When you add 2.1 it will truncate the decimal.

Comment: That doesn't explain the error.

Comment: I just ran it in Xcode, and it works fine. What compiler are you using?

Comment: That's why I asked the OP about details of the toolchain.

Comment: @Masoud That doesn't answer the question about the toolchain. Codeblocks is an IDE that can be used with various compilers.

Comment: @Masoud Which version exactly? sigh ...

Comment: I use code::blocks 13.12

Comment: @Masoud use a more recent version, e.g. codeblocks 16.01.  (But it would also be good to use latest compiler from mingw-w64.org , as cb 16.01 is still bundle with a fairly old compiler)